# How can I measure the significance of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to understand deep learning's algorithms and statistical logic. I could not understand, however, the case where two algorithms, A and B, exist with 75% and 78% test set accuracies respectively.

Does that mean that Algorithm A is significantly better than Algorithm B if the test set contains 100 instances?

Answer (score 0):

Stated in this way, you cannot say anything about significance in a statistical safe way.

The main issue is that you don't have an "error" associated to the accuracies, so you don't know how much stable are those results. In the so-called frequentist approach one of the key principle is that the result of a single experiment is by definition exact.

In your case, you have two single experiments, A and B, and that's it.

If, instead, you perform much more experiments, as example by iterating in shuffling the instances, splitting in train/test set, and finally train the algorithms, you will have two distributions, one for each algorithm, and now you can try to state something about significance.